# why would MySQL not use keys when there are possible keys

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, primary-key

So whenever I EXPLAIN my query, I often get instances in which it states certain fields as possible keys but then the key table will be null...

Why would MySQL do this and decide to use no keys when in fact it can use a possible key?

Comment: Can you show an example query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't always use a key, for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B where A.id = B.id;
```

Although `id` is a possible key for both lookups, it can't be *used* for both.  One of the tables must do a full scan.

Answer (score 8):

The optimizer may reasonably calculate that using an index would result in poorer performance than say a full table scan.

I'll give you an example:

Say, you have a gender field which is indexed but 90% of your records are female. The optimizer could use the index but it is probably more efficient just to do a full table scan as the spread of the data is skewed.

Comment: If 90% were female, MySQL may use the index if you selected the males. Though it would have low cardinality, selectivity would still be high. It still depends on the number of rows that would be returned. If you tried to select the females, MySQL would want to do a full table scan.

Comment: Exactly - the query and spread of the data will be used by the optimizer to determine the best execution plan.